# delet row in custom wp db

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to delete a row from my custom table created in WP db. The problem is that the delete always removes the last row, not the row desired. Not sure if the `$_POST['field_id'];` was passed properly. Any ideas?

```
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$table_add_one = $wpdb->prefix . "wwy_data_one";
$table_add_two = $wpdb->prefix . "wwy_data_two";


$row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_wwy_data_one WHERE user_id=$user_id  ORDER BY slide_number");
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    echo "<table class='display'>"; 
    echo "<th>Slide#</th>";
    //echo "<th>User ID</th>";
    echo "<th>Map</th>";
    echo "<th>Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Lenght</th>";
    echo "<th>Caption</th>";
    echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "<th>Markers</th>";
    if (!$row){ echo "<tr><td colspan='6'>No Slides created!</td></tr>";}

    foreach ( $row as $row ) 
    { 
    // delete row
    $warn_del = '"Are you sure to delete this slide?"';

    if(isset($_POST['field_id'])) {
     $table_add_one = $wpdb->prefix . "wwy_data_one";   
     $the_value = $_POST['field_id'];
     $rows_affected_one = $wpdb->delete( $table_add_one, array( 'field_id' => $the_value ));     
    }             
     echo "<tr>";    
     echo "<td>" . $row->slide_number . "</td>";
    // echo "<td>" . $row->user_id . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row->map_type . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row->date . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row->length . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row->caption . "</td>";  
     echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='field_id' value='$row->field_id'><input onclick='return confirm($warn_del);' type='submit' value='delete' class='delete'></td>";   
    echo '<td><label><input type="radio" name="geo" rel="'.$row->slide_number.'" />Show</label></td>';  
    echo "</tr>";
    } 
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Well... if you're not sure, why don't you debug in order to be sure ???

Comment: I'm not sure this affects it, but change your first `$row = $wpdb->get_results(` to `$rows = $wpdb->get_results(`, and your `foreach ( $row as $row )` to `foreach ($rows as $row)`. PHP's variable collision there could be giving you an unexpected result.

Comment: I'm using the blackbox plugin but it's not giving me any errors related to this action. JBNUNN, I tried your suggestion but getting the same result. Thanks

Comment: ok, I'm sure $_POST['field_id']; is passed properly!

Comment: just adding:  field_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED No None AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac If setting the field solved it, you should answer your question below so that future searchers will know how to fix should they run across it.

Comment: so for some reason when I click on delete the $_POST[field_id] value is the last value of the item in the table.

Comment: when I replace $_POST with $_GET I'm getting this in url ?field_id=53&delete=delete&field_id=66&field_id=71 and the last value is deleted. How can I trim it and have the first value processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='field_id' value='$row->field_id'><input onclick='return confirm($warn_del);' type='submit' value='delete' class='delete'></td>";
```

use it like this

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='field_id' value='" . $row->field_id . "' placeholder='Delete'  onclick='return confirm($warn_del);'><td>";
```

wualla!