# Wordpress plugin - Deleting only the row I'm clicking?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently working on a Wordpress plugin, and ran into trouble when simple trying have a delete button for each of my rows..
My idea is like many others, that every single row has an ID, and when I click the button that belongs to that row - It should be deleted..
I also tried doing what this guy did...
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428783/delet-row-in-custom-wp-db#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428783/delet-row-in-custom-wp-db#_=_)

This is what I got:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            global $wpdb;
                $rows = $wpdb->get_results(
                "
                SELECT *
                FROM skibInfo
                WHERE skib_status = 'Forventet skib'

                "
                );

            foreach ($rows as $row)
            {   

            if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])){
                global $wpdb;
                $table = $wpdb->prefix."skibInfo";
                $skib_nr = $_POST['ID'];
                $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'ID' => $skib_nr), array( '%d' ));
            }
                echo "<tr>";

                    echo"<td>".$row->field1."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row->field2."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row->field3."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row->field4."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row->field5."</td>";

                    echo'<td><input type="submit" value="' . $row->ID . '" name="deleteItem" /></td>';

                echo "</tr>";


            }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong $_POST value as the delete ID.  You are checking for 'deleteItem' correctly, but you're using 'ID'.  Change:

```
$skib_nr = $_POST['ID'];
```

to:

```
$skib_nr = $_POST['deleteItem'];
```